# ASLR when forking a new child

Tags: fork, mmap, aslr

While forking a child, I see that the ASLR is inherited from the parent.

Is there a way to unamp for example: libc from the child process,

& then mmap it again so ASLR will take an effect on libc ?

I would like to be able to do ASLR on the child process,

I know it sounds impossible since somehow the dynamic loader should resolve again the symbols,

I wonder if it can succeed

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it at all? What's the point of ASLR of child if parent has control of child anyway?

Comment: What operating system?